# Powershell: Extraction of AAD group membership, comparing membership and deleting users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell, hashset

I have a list of groups names in a .yaml file. I need to aggregate the membership of these groups into a single Hash set (Hashset $Yaml_Members)

I have a different group and I need to populate a different hashset with its membership (Hashset $AAD_Members)

I need to compare these two hashsets and add any users, that are in $Yaml_Members but are not in $AAD_Members and remove any users that are in $AAD_Members, but not in $Yaml_Members.

Could you please take a look and assist? (PS newbie here :D )

```
$groups = Get-Content -Path "FilePath" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Yaml

$Yaml_Members = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]

$AAD_Members =  New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]

foreach ($group in $groups) {

    $fullGroup = Get-MgGroup -Filter "displayName eq '$group'"

    [String[]]$Yaml_Ids = @(Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $fullGroup.Id).Id    #This should make a list of user IDs
    $Yaml_members.UnionWith($Yaml_Ids)        

}


[String[]]$AAD_Ids = @(Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId "GroupID").Id             #This should make a list of user IDs
$AAD_Members.UnionWith($AAD_Ids)                                                  


                                                                            #Modify $AAD_Members to contain all elements that are present in itself, $Yaml_Members, or both | This will contain user IDs
$AddUsers = $AAD_Members.UnionWith($Yaml_Members)

                                                                            #Remove all items from $AAD_Members that aren't in $Yaml_Members | This will contain user IDs
$RemoveUsers = $AAD_Members.IntersectWith($Yaml_Members)


                                                                            #Add users from $AddUsers
foreach ($Add_user in $AddUsers) {

    New-MgGroupMember -GroupId "GroupID" -DirectoryObjectId $Add_user

}

                                                                            #Remove users from $RemoveUsers
foreach ($Remove_user in $RemoveUsers) {

    Remove-MgGroupMemberByRef -GroupId "GroupID" -DirectoryObjectId $Remove_user
    
    }
type here
```